# Multiple filters in a single stream

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have written a code using Java 8 streams but trying to refactor.

I have filtered the list with different criteria and storing it into a new list. Is there any way to filter all the criteria at once and store the group of result into a list. I don't know how to explain that.

Here is my code and just need to refactor it.

```
List<A> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
List<A> aList= new ArrayList<>();

A objectA = new A();

List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();
bList.add(new B(5700));
bList.add(new B(5750));
bList.add(new B(5800));
bList.add(new B(5812));
bList.add(new B(5803));
bList.add(new B(5802));

objectA.setMyList(bList);

aList.add(objectA);

aList.stream()
    .forEach(
        a -> {
            if(!a.getMyList.isEmpty()){
                List<B> groupA =
                    a.getMyList.stream()
                        .filter(b -> b.getType() == 5700 || b.getType() == 5750)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                List<B> groupB =
                    a.getMyList.stream()
                        .filter(b -> b.getType() == 5800 || b.getType() == 5810)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                List<B> groupC =
                    a.getMyList.stream()
                        .filter(b -> b.getType() == 5802 || b.getType() == 5812)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                List<B> groupD =
                    a.getMyList.stream()
                        .filter(b -> b.getType() == 5803 || b.getType() == 5813)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());



                if(!groupA.isEmpty()){
                    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupA));
                }
                if(!groupB.isEmpty()){
                    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupB));
                }
                if(!groupC.isEmpty()){
                    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupC));
                }
                if(!groupD.isEmpty()){
                    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupD));
                }
             }
        }
    );


private A getAWithGroupList(A a, List<B> group) {
    A a = (A) a.clone();
    a.setMyList(group);
    return a;
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a problem with [Revision 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37516640/revisions). `myList` is empty, and so is `myList.stream()`!

Comment: @dorukayhan I have added dummy data in the list.

Comment: Btw, this question seems a bit more fitting to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Oh, I did not know about that. Thanks anyways

Comment: I would go for an Enum approach which contains the two possibles. The Enum would have a method such as 'fromInt(Integer type)' and would return an Enum value. I would then group the stream elements by enum type and apply for each group the  'getAWithGroupList()' method. It would make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Wrap the repeating code in a method:

```
private List<B> listifyAndfilter(A a, Predicate<List<B>> check){
    return a.getMyList.stream().filter(check).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then you can do:

```
List<B> groupA = listifyAndFilter(a, b -> b.getType() == 5700 || b.getType() == 5750),
        groupB = listifyAndFilter(a, b -> b.getType() == 5800 || b.getType() == 5810),
        groupC = listifyAndFilter(a, b -> b.getType() == 5802 || b.getType() == 5812),
        groupD = listifyAndFilter(a, b -> b.getType() == 5803 || b.getType() == 5813);
```

Note the commas at the ends of the lines.

**Unrelated but useful:** You can also combine these if-statements:

```
if(!groupA.isEmpty()){
    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupA));
}
if(!groupB.isEmpty()){
    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupB));
}
if(!groupC.isEmpty()){
    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupC));
}
if(!groupD.isEmpty()){
    finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, groupD));
}
```

into this for-each loop:

```
for (List<B> group : new List<B>[]{groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD}) // Packs the lists in an array and iterates over the array
    if(!group.isEmpty())
        finalList.add(getAWithGroupList(a, group));
```

Comment: Instead of getting the result in different group List is there any possibility in Java 8 to do multiple filters inline and get the result as List of List. `a.getMyList.stream().filter(---).filter(---).filter(---).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: BTW we cant create generic array new List<B>[]

Comment: @UmairAnsari You can use `Arrays.asList(groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD)` instead of the array: `for (List<B> group : Arrays.asList(groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD)) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

The biggest obstacle is that the rationale behind your criteria is unknown. So when we can’t simplify it, we have to declare these group explicitly:

```
Integer[][] groups={ { 5700, 5750 }, {5800, 5810}, {5802, 5812}, {5803, 5813} };

Map<Integer, Integer[]> type2group = Arrays.stream(groups)
    .collect(HashMap::new, (m,g) -> Arrays.stream(g).forEach(i->m.put(i, g)), Map::putAll);

ArrayList<A> finalList = aList.stream()
    .map(a -> a.getMyList().stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(b -> type2group.get(b.getType())),
        group2b -> Arrays.stream(groups)
            .map(g -> group2b.getOrDefault(g, Collections.emptyList()))
            .map(listB -> getAWithGroupList(a, listB))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))))
    .collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```

The two dimensional array is the easiest-to-maintain way to specify these groups. To process them efficiently afterward, the first step converts them into a map from type (result of `B.getType`) to an identifier of the desired group, which is just a subarray of our complete `group` specifier (the actual type of the group identifier is irrelevant as we will encounter the same objects later-on, so the fact that arrays have no `equals` method doesn’t matter here).

The second step performs the grouping of the `B` instances for each `A` and assembles the `finalList`.

Note that if there are absent groups, the above solution will create empty lists for them. If you don’t want to have them, you can change the last step of the solution to

```
ArrayList<A> finalList = aList.stream()
    .map(a -> a.getMyList().stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(b -> type2group.get(b.getType())),
        group2b -> Arrays.stream(groups)
            .map(g -> group2b.get(g)).filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(listB -> getAWithGroupList(a, listB))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))))
    .collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```

---

Alternatively, the following code is more compact, but less efficient as it will process the data multiple times (traverse all `B`s for each group and perform linear search within the groups):

```
Integer[][] groups={ { 5700, 5750 }, {5800, 5810}, {5802, 5812}, {5803, 5813} };

List<A> finalList = aList.stream().flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(groups)
        .map(g -> getAWithGroupList(a, a.getMyList().stream()
            .filter(b -> Arrays.asList(g).contains(b.getType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In case there might be absent groups and you don’t want to have empty lists for them, you can change it to

```
List<A> finalList = aList.stream().flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(groups)
        .map(g -> a.getMyList().stream()
            .filter(b -> Arrays.asList(g).contains(b.getType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
        .map(l -> getAWithGroupList(a, l)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have list of `objectA`. My values are stored in `aList` and you are not iterating that.

Comment: @Umair Ansari: you should look closer (or just try running it). Both solutions are iterating `aList` and, as said, the second solution will even traverse it multiple times which is the reason why it is less efficient. Just another hint: every browser has a search function so in case you don’t see it, let the browser highlight the occurrences of `aList`…

Comment: In the first solution where the ObjectA is coming from? I need to pass the object added into the aList.

Comment: You are right, I was misled by your example code which has only one `A` instance (and didn’t consider the other properties of `A` besides the overwritten `myList`, that are retained by `clone()`). I fixed the answer.